# Behavior of FOR XML AUTO SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml

I was fiddling with XML AUTO and XML RAW to see how they behave. The test db is `AdventureWorks2012`.

```
SELECT TOP 20  Cust.CustomerID AS C1,
        Cust.TerritoryID,
        OrderHeader.CustomerID AS C2,
        OrderHeader.SalesOrderID,
        OrderHeader.Status

FROM Sales.Customer Cust
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader OrderHeader
ON Cust.CustomerID = OrderHeader.CustomerID
FOR XML RAW('MyRow'), ELEMENTS
```

XML RAW's simplicity just puts every element in the same level

```
<MyRow>
<C1>29825</C1>
<TerritoryID>5</TerritoryID>
<C2>29825</C2>
<SalesOrderID>43659</SalesOrderID>
<Status>5</Status>
```

While for XML AUTO

```
SELECT TOP 20  Cust.CustomerID,
        Cust.TerritoryID,
        OrderHeader.CustomerID,
        OrderHeader.SalesOrderID,
        OrderHeader.Status
FROM Sales.Customer Cust
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader OrderHeader
ON Cust.CustomerID = OrderHeader.CustomerID
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

I have

```
<Cust>
<CustomerID>29825</CustomerID>
<TerritoryID>5</TerritoryID>
<OrderHeader>
    <CustomerID>29825</CustomerID>
    <SalesOrderID>43659</SalesOrderID>
    <Status>5</Status>
</OrderHeader>
</Cust>
```

XML AUTO decides to group all under `Cust` tag. How does it come to this conclusion that `Cust` somehow encloses and "at a higher level" than `OrderHeader`. Why does it decide to group all `OrderHeader`'s columns under OrderHeader tag and not the same for `Cust` ? Before executing I thought that it would be

```
<Cust>
    <CustomerID>29825</CustomerID>
    <TerritoryID>5</TerritoryID>
</Cust>
<OrderHeader>
    <CustomerID>29825</CustomerID>
    <SalesOrderID>43659</SalesOrderID>
    <Status>5</Status>
</OrderHeader>
```

**Update**

It's a hunch but I start to think SQL Server will take the table of the column first mentioned to be the outer tag,

For example,

```
SELECT TOP 20  OrderHeader.CustomerID,,
               Cust.CustomerID,
               Cust.TerritoryID,
               OrderHeader.SalesOrderID,
               OrderHeader.Status
```

Even when I mix the column order, it will still group columns of OrderHeader together, and Cust is a subgroup

```
<OrderHeader>
<CustomerID>29825</CustomerID>
<SalesOrderID>43659</SalesOrderID>
<Status>5</Status>
<Cust>
<CustomerID>29825</CustomerID>
<TerritoryID>5</TerritoryID>
</Cust>
</OrderHeader>
```

Comment: I guess that wouldnt really make since if you had multiple results.  some type of nesting needs to occur to link the elements?  if you put the SalesOrderHeader fields first in the query Cust will be inside of OrderHeader

Comment: why does not it make sense if you had multiple result ? For what I know, XML AUTO does not create well-formed document unless we specify a Root. I have tested and yes, if we put orderHeader first, Cust will be under orderHeader.

Comment: well if you wanted to get all of the information for a customer you'd need to query the xml twice, if they were not nested. I guess they figured that wouldnt be the best approach and people would probably complain.

Comment: I have updated the question. Seems like they just take the first table as outer tag.